# cross join pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 01-03-2022 12:40:00 | orange |
| aaa | 01-03-2022 12:40:10 | apple |
| aaa | 01-03-2022 12:40:00 | kiwi |
| aaa | 01-03-2022 12:40:08 | apple |
| bbb | 15-03-2022 13:10:10 | orange |
| bbb | 15-03-2022 13:10:18 | apple |
| bbb | 15-03-2022 13:10:40 | kiwi |
| bbb | 15-03-2022 13:10:15 | apple |

In the above dataframe, whenever a value 'orange' is present for a user in column C, i want to select the earliest date for the same user and that date should correspond to value apple in column C. So if a value 'orange' is present in column C then that value should be retained but the values (date) in column B should correspond to that of 'apple'

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 01-03-2022 12:40:08 | orange |
| bbb | 15-03-2022 13:10:15 | orange |

Comment: IIUC, earliest date for orange and earliest date for apple?

Comment: earliest date for apple but retain the value as orange in column C, if 'orange' is present

Answer (score 2):

```
# Import Your Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','bbb','bbb'],
'B':['01-03-2022 12:40:00','01-03-2022 12:40:10','01-03-2022 12:40:00','01-03-2022 12:40:08','15-03-2022 13:10:10','15-03-2022 13:10:18','15-03-2022 13:10:40','15-03-2022 13:10:15'],
'C':['orange','apple','kiwi','apple','orange','apple','kiwi','apple']})
df.sort_values(['A','C','B'],ascending=[True,True,True],inplace=True)
df_orange = df.loc[df['C']=='orange']
df_apple = df.loc[df['C']=='apple']

# Data Pre-Process
df_orange_v2 = df_orange.groupby(['A']).first().reset_index()
df_apple_v2 = df_apple.groupby(['A']).first().reset_index()

# Merge Process and Clean Data
df_v2 = pd.merge(df_orange_v2, df_apple_v2[['A','B']], how='left', left_on='A',right_on='A')
df_v2.rename(columns={'B_y':'B'}, inplace = True)
df_v2.drop(['B_x'],axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_final = df_v2[['A','B','C']]
df_final
```

Hi Brother, I have adjust the code for you, please run it and see if this is what you want, if you have any question please let me know

Thanks
Leon

Comment: It sorts and group by values in A and C column, but how do i drop 'apple' from column C and retain 'orange' in column C and the time that corresponds to 'apple' in column B. essentially there should be only one row for 'aaa' and one row for 'bbb' in the resulting dataframe.

Comment: Hi Brother, So for one group from 'A' you only need one record, and you need Apple's time for Orange? if you don't mind, give me a little bit time to adjust the code for your. Thanks Leon

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: I know what you want, please give me a little bit time to adjust the code for you. ^_^ Thanks Leon

Comment: I have adjusted the code for you, please take a look brother Thanks Leon

Answer (score 1):

So we do two steps

```
out = df[df.A.isin(df.loc[df['C'].isin(['orange']),'A'])]

out = out.loc[out.C.eq('apple')].sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A')

out['C'] = 'orange'
```